# How to install packages which are present on startup in alpine diskless

Tags: raspberry-pi, alpine-linux, persistence

I've installed alpine linux on an R-Pi using [instructions on Alpine's wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi).  The instructions note:

> Alpine Linux will be installed in [diskless mode](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installation#Diskless_Mode), hence, Alpine Local Backup (`lbu`) is required to save modifications between reboots.

I have a persistent package cache setup for `apk`, and that is working, but as far as the actually installed packages are concerned: the manual for `lbu` it only saves `/etc` by default.

What I'm struggling with is figuring out how I'm supposed to install packages so they are there ready when the system boots.  At the moment, the system boots with nothing new installed and only installs packages I've previously asked for if I type:

```
apk add
```

Some of the packages I want (including avahi) have daemons which are supposed to be initiated through scripts in `/etc/init.d`.  Even if I save `/etc` the daemons will not be installed and ready to start.

What am I supposed to do to ensure packages (including daemons) are correctly installed when the system boots?

Answer (score 1):

I worked with alpine in the past here are some of my notes that might apply.

```
Make sure /etc/apk/cache is setup properly
To save /etc/
    lbu commit -d

To save /root
    lbu include /root
    lbu commit -d
```

From what I read of how alpine works, it installs each package fresh every boot. So it just has to have the apk file in the cache and the config in /etc. If there is any data that needs to get saved that comes from the outside and not configuration or 'write once', e.g. database tables, then they should be on another disk that you mount on startup.

Alpine does have an "install to disk" mode as well so that it can behave just like a small musl version of debian for instance. That may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. For me it's not installing on restart. I'm starting to believe I'm experiencing a bug. Not sure if I misconfigured something, if my install was somehow corrupt, or the armhf build has/ had a genuine bug. I need to rule out the first two first.